# Consequences of conducting under-powered trials?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-power

I have been taught that under-powered trials cause effects of practical importance being not detected. Thus, that's the reason why we mainly work with power >= 0.8. However, I'm curious..

In what situation do we conduct under-powered trials? Power =0.6

And,how do we interpret the data knowing that there is a heightened type 2 error?

Answer (score -1):

We do not conduct under-powered trials... unless there is just no way of getting more data. The interpretation is based on the confidence intervals. If these are large you can surmise that the results are likely to vary a lot from sample to sample.